# Why cant i access a certain website from my PC but can do it from my Phone?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, browser

so, i cant access my university's website in any browser on my computer (home) (edge, chrome, brave), i get the same error on all of them (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE), i tried changing my DNS, incognito mode, virtual machine, hosts file, nothing works, BUT, if i try from my phone, that is connected to the same network, it works fine, if i go to another computer in the same network, it also works fine, it's just my computer that can't access it, i dont have a VPN.

i also have another problem that might be related, twitch.tv is completely broken on my google chrome, i can only fix it by formatting my PC, i've tried reinstalling chrome, deleting all the files i could find, if i format the PC, reinstall the browser with all the same extensions, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your phone is using the university network and not the cellular network for your web access? Have you reached out to the university IT people to determine whether they may have a deliberate block on the site, or some other issue?

Comment: ok, i meant, i cant access the university's website, nto a website from a university computer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, connecting from inside the Uni network doesn't work.
However, connecting from the phone that connects through the phone company
worked, mainly because this connection comes from outside the Uni network.

This means that the Uni routers do not support a back connection of the type
of *computer->router->internet->uni web->router->computer*.

In such cases, the website might be reachable via address, for example
`https://uni-server/uni-website`.

I suggest that reach out to the network administrator or the website administrator,
to ask how to access the website from the inside of the Uni network.

Comment: apparently i suck at writing english lol, im unable to communicate my actual problem.

Comment: No problem, I though I understood. Take your time to edit your post and clarify the situation. A drawing may be worth more than words.

Comment: The way I read the question, it sounds like computers outside the Uni network can't connect to the site, but computers on the Uni network can, as can phones (which are outside the Uni network). So, it's not a question of outside vs on the Uni network.

Comment: @RobH: You might be right. From careful reading, it might have something to do with some installed software or extension on the home computer (if it's not a laptop that he takes to Uni).