# Different situation from: Why cant i access a certain website from my PC but can do it from my Phone?

Tags: networking, router, website, maintenance

I read [the question of a fellow user](https://superuser.com/questions/1616774/why-cant-i-access-a-certain-website-from-my-pc-but-can-do-it-from-my-phone) who has a similar situation, but with different perceived characteristics, so I decided to open a new question. I can't access [my college website](http://www.soyeconomicas.com) from my home pc, using my home ISP and not the college network. But I can access it from my phone, using the same network as my pc, the only difference is that my phone uses wifi but my pc, wired ethernet, to the same router. The website tends to be saturated these days due to the traffic of my fellow students who try to access it, giving them problems. Everyone trying to get courses assigned.

From my pc, I tried using Linux and Windows 10. I also tried using Firefox and Edge. I even tried using also my neighbors different ISP, through an ethernet cable. I tried turning off my Windows Firewall. Nothing worked. I can't access the website from my pc, although I can access any other website. I do have some loading issues, but I can access the other websites, except the college website. I tried many times. Each time when I couldn't access it I tried successfully other websites. My pc does have an issue of maintenance because I haven't changed the thermal paste of the cpu fan for many years, so it overheats. But still, it is the one website I cannot access, I can access pretty much all other websites I have tried.

Any advice will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really trying to connect to `www.soyeconomicas.com` as shown, or to `soyeconomicas.com` (no www)? The latter exists and works; the former is nonexistent according to the authoritative nameservers and most others I've tried (though _some_ SERVFAIL!). Many browsers will silently add www; I don't know if any (such as your phone) might silently subtract.

Comment: It was the latter indeed, maybe the phone did what you indicate.

Answer (score -1):

you check the host again.

localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

## 127.0.0.1       localhost